# Creating multiple has_many through associations from an array of IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, has-many-through

I have models `User`, `Photo` and `Favorite`, where `favorites` is a join table from `users` to `photos`, i.e.:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorites
  has_many :photos, through: `favorites`
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorites
  has_many :users, through: `favorites`
end

class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :photo
end
```

Say that `@user` is an instance of `User` and `photo_ids` is an array of primary keys of Photos. What's the fastest and/or most succinct way to add all of those photos to `@user.photos`?

The best I can up with is:

```
@user.favorites.create( photo_ids.map { |id| {photo_id: id } } )
```

But this seems pretty verbose to me. Does Rails not have a better way of handling this?

Other questions talk about creating multiple `has_many: through:` associations through a nested form but I'm trying to do this in a JSON API so there are no forms involved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

```
@user.photos << Photo.find_all_by_id(photo_ids)
```

Comment: Didn't realise you could use `<<` on an ActiveRecord association. Thanks!

Comment: Also note that object on the right is an array - it still works though.

Comment: Actually I don't think this would work, wouldn't `Photo.find_by_id` only return one result? `Photo.where(id: photo_ids)` or `Photo.find(photo_ids)` both work fine though.

Comment: Cool. Worth noting that `find_by_*` and `find_all_by_*` syntax is deprecated in Rails 4. I used `where` but the effect is the same.

Comment: In rails 4 I would probably go for `find_all_by(id: photo_ids)` - it feels slightly better than `where` here but obviously there is no difference. :) Also note that Photo.find(photos_id) will raise an exception if it fails to find any of the records.

Comment: Again, `find_all_by` is deprecated in Rails 4 and will not work.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to assign to the `singular_collection_ids` to replace the photos.

```rb
@user.photo_ids = photo_ids
```

If you want to "add" to the collection, you can use `|=`

```rb
@user.photo_ids |= photo_ids
```